# Best way to gain C++ working experience for a job in games (coming from C#)

Tags: c++, c#, software-engineering, jobs

I am a software developer, experienced with C# (5 years experience) alongside a few other languages.

My "dream job" is working in video games as a developer.

Most jobs require knowledge of C++, which i currently don't have (except for some of the basics).

I've looked around, and most big game companies require something along 3-5 years of previous experience with C++.

My question is -- what would be a good route to get myself up to this required experience level, coming from C# ?

I've thought of some possible ways to do it:

Get more knowledge about C++ from books.
Participate in open-source projects that are written in C++.
What would be the best way to learn C++ and have working-level experience with it, in particular for the game industry?

Comment: Nobody cares much how or where you got your experience from, or whether you were paid for it or not. If you want experience in C++, start programming C++.

Comment: @liortal Repost: [See also What are some great tips for a beginner?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/15856/998) (some weirdo deleted all my comments on this thread).

Answer (score 29):

As a game developer, my main concern hiring a C# guy would be a lack of low-level knowledge.

So, consider a project where your work entails low-level optimization like re-arranging the data layout of classes or rewriting code to take advantage of SIMD instructions. Take a C++ open-source game, optimize it, and post the framerate increase on your resume.

If I were interviewing you, I'd care less about the C++ on your resume and more about whether you can answer my C/C++/low-level interview questions. I'll take a stab at some standard interview questions you might have trouble with (warning: I'm no C# expert):

- How are C++ classes laid out in memory? Draw a diagram of bytes. Include vtable pointers and padding/alignment of member variables. What about a derived class? What about a multiply-derived class?
- How does a virtual function call happen, at a low level? Talk about assembly operations like reading a value in memory and jumping to an address.
- Know about C-style cast, static_cast, and dynamic_cast between pointers to types with various inheritance relationships. For example, classes B and C both derive from class A. What happens when you try to cast from A* to B* (or B* to C*) using these various casts? (I mention because I don't think C# would even allow these specific casts.)
- Why is it terrible to pass an stl vector by value, instead of by reference? (I mention because most types in C# are reference types and thus it is basically impossible to make this kind of mistake in C#.)
- What does it mean for a structure or function to be cache-friendly? Why might a structure-of-arrays perform better than an array-of-structures?
- Understand heap, stack, and static memory. If an object was allocated with new, where does it live in the process's memory? What about a local variable? A global variable?
- What's a memory leak? What are some best practices for avoiding them? (I mention because there's no *delete* in C#!)
- How would you debug a memory access violation crash? What about if the crash happened in some middleware library for which you don't have source code?

Comment: Repost:  I already know the usefulness of knowing where vtable pointers are in memory because I ran into a [bug involving that before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992786/vftptr-is-null/992846#992846).  However, how is the 2nd question useful at all?  How does knowing "assembly level operations like reading a value into memory" make one a competent C++ programmer?

Comment: My Blizzard interview for WoW UI intern spot touched on point 1, 2, 3(to a lesser degree), 5, and 7.
He also asked questions about debugging/testing(similar to point 8)

I think this answer is exactly spot on even in the general case for upper-level game development companies.

Comment: @DeanKnight I don't doubt that.  But I'd still like to know how the OP thinks that kind of question _makes someone a good C++ programmer_ (original question being about how to become a better C++ programmer) as opposed to just helping someone ace the interviews.

Comment: You sound skeptical, bobobobo, but your link about the vtable pointer bug is a great example of how knowing the internals of virtual function calls is useful. Consider a similar bug where, instead of the vtable pointer being *null*, it's *garbage*. One way to *realize* it's garbage would be to step through the disassembly of the virtual function call and see your program go off into nowhere instead of going to a valid vtable or a valid method.

Answer (score 1):

What Eric said. I would also add to avoid "new" where it's not neccesarly. It's very common in C# but considered as bad practice in C++11 and also slower than stack allocation and more dangerous because you have to manually deallocate it.

I would be also careful with old books, they teach old practices. I personally prefer reliable forums/websites, stackoverflow/isocpp.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for broader, more general advice/recommendations on what to do, rather than language specifics to study.

Comment: "Avoiding `new`" is a really not a sensible recommendation. You use `new` when you have pointers.  If `class Derived : Base`, then a `Base var = Derived();` is illegal, but `Base *var = new Derived();` is legal.  So you need pointers to get polymorphism to work right, a lot.

Comment: Yes, but you can use std::unique_ptr to accomplish polymorphism and avoid the naked pointer (although you will still have the new keyword in the unique_ptr constructor)

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a mistake in the above comment.  `Base var = Derived()` _would work_, but it would be [sliced](http://stackoverflow.com/q/274626/111307) and, unbeknownst to you, information lost in `var`.  To fix the slicing problem, you could use pointers.